# What is the difference between using GetAsyncKeyState() by checking with its return value as -32767 and 0x8000?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am extremely confused by the sheer amount of how many different answers there are about GetAsyncKeyState(), I know what it does, but the confusing part is it's return value. I've seen many different examples on how people use this, but the main two are the following:

**First:**

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(KEY) == -32767)
```

**Second:**

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(KEY) & 0x8000)
```

The first confusing bit about this is that when using the Windows Calculator and converting `-32767` to a hexadecimal, it is equal to `0x8001`, so already they are not comparing the same thing. As far as I am aware (and please correct me if I understood incorrectly), `0x8000` is checking that the key is currently pressed but `0x8001` is doing the same while at the same time while telling you that it had been pressed after the last time `GetAsyncKeyState()` was called on that key.

Here is some sample code of the second confusion/problem with these different ways of essentially doing the same thing, yet at the same time achieving different results...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
int main() {
        
            while (true) {
                for (int KEY = 8; KEY <= 190; KEY++)
                {
                    if (GetAsyncKeyState(KEY) == -32767) {
                        std::cout << char(KEY) << std::endl;
                    }
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

As you can see in the code above, I am using the "First" option to check if the key has been pressed. With this option no matter how fast you type (only tested under 120wpm) it won't repeat letters, as long as you are not holding them for a strangely longer time than a normal person holds a letter to type, if you do hold them you get the expected behaviour of it just repeating it (printing it out to the screen). It works perfectly when typing at normal speeds or fast speeds up to 120wpm tested, no repeated keys (I will explain what I mean by 'repeated keys'). Here is some code using the "Second" way...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>    
int main() {

    while (true) {
        for (int KEY = 8; KEY <= 190; KEY++)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(KEY) & 0x8000) {
                std::cout << char(KEY) << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With this one I run into a problem where no matter how fast I tap the key it will repeat a few times at minimum, you can try it yourself if you want to see what I mean, but as an example:
If I were to type `H` once this would be the result for First and Second respectively:

```
First:
H
Second:
H
H
H
H
H
.....etc maybe a few more times maybe one or two less times..... highly inconsistent
```

Why do they have very different outcomes even though in theory they should do the same thing (even though `-32767` is not the same as `0x8000`, it is the thing I've more commonly seen out there apart from `0x8000`).

Comment: @HansPassant Yes I have read that it is the correct way of doing it, but yet it is the only way that causes the duplication 'error' even though it is not an error, it causes unintended behaviour from what I want to do and from what most people want to achieve, and there is no easy fix for it, the ones that I have tried made it too slow for it to log all keys typed fast (if they are different keys, so literally nearly every word).

Comment: I have read the part where you **think** it means, and I know that if you searched for Microsoft's official documentation, you would **know** what it means, because Microsoft's website would tell you!

Comment: you would know **precisely** what the difference between 0x8000 and 0x8001 (-32767) is.

Comment: @user253751 Im sorry to tell you but I wouldn't, first of all not everyone understands everything that appear on things like docs.microsoft, for some newbies like me things seem extremely difficult to understand and maybe for you it might be unbelievable but I have been researching and trying things out on my own for over 4hours now, I really started with barely any knowledge what hex even is or what decimals and all that stuff is, and yes I need to learn more and I will but not everyone understands everything perfectly sir

Comment: @user253751 but the confusing part is not as much as to what 0x8000 and 0x8001 as a return value means, but more like why (even though 0x8001 which is supposed to be the same as  -32767) differ so much in what the output looks like, just like I stated in my question. Another one is why 0x8000 is used as extensively as -32767 is even though they don't mean the same thing 'in concept'.

Comment: They **don't** mean the same thing! 0x8000 and -32767 are **different numbers**. There's no "in concept" about it! They **are different**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `GetAsyncKeyState` returns a `SHORT`, which is a 16-bit signed integer.

The highest bit of the returned value represents whether the key is currently being held down. You can test this bit with `GetAsyncKeyState(KEY) & 0x8000`.

The lowest bit also has a meaning: It specifies whether the key has been pressed since the last call to `GetAsyncKeyState`. But this feature is only provided for backwards-compatibility with [16-bit Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_3.1x) and should not be relied upon for modern 32-bit or 64-bit applications. Therefore, it should be ignored. See the [official Microsoft documentation for this function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) for further information. If you really want to test this bit (which you should generally not do), then you could do it with the expression `GetAsyncKeyState(KEY) & 0x0001`.

The expression

```
GetAsyncKeyState(KEY) == -32767
```

will only be true if the highest bit and the lowest bit are set, and all other bits are zero.

This is bad programming practice. Even if this code currently works in all version of Microsoft Windows, it should not be assumed that all other bits will be zero, as the meaning of the other bits is undefined. For example, Microsoft may assign a meaning to one of these currently unused bits in a future version of Windows. Therefore, as a general rule, only the defined bits should be tested.

As stated above, there are only two bits defined, but one is unreliable and only provided for backwards compatibility; it should therefore not be used. For this reason, only the highest bit should be tested with the expression `GetAsyncKeyState(KEY) & 0x8000`.

The reason why your first program behaves differently from your second program is that your first program requires both bits to be set, whereas your second program requires only one bit to be set and ignores the other bit. In other words, your first program only prints something if `GetAsyncKeyState` reports that the button is currently being held down AND was pressed since the previous call to the function, whereas the second program only requires that the button is currently being held down.

It is not quite clear what the Microsoft documentation means by "was pressed since the previous call". It probably means whether a [WM_KEYDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown) message was generated since the previous function call. That is probably why your first program only prints something when you start holding the button, instead of printing something continuously while the button is being held down.

Even if your first program does exactly what you want, for the reasons stated above, it is unreliable. Therefore, if you only want one notification per keystroke, I recommend that you do not use `GetAsyncKeyState`, but instead process `WM_KEYDOWN` messages in your [message loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues).